# A door has a keypad lock. The keys on the lock are labelled with the digits 1 through 9, and the combination is five digits long.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> A door has a keypad lock.  The keys on the lock are labelled with the digits 1 through 9, and the combination is five digits long.  How many different combinations are possible for this lock?
>
> How many of the combinations either start or end with an even number?

**For the first part:**

```
It has 9 options and we select 5 different options.

Since order matters it is permutations : 9P5

9P5 = 9! / (9-5)!

Number of combinations = 9*8*7*6*5 = 15120
```

But then I'm at a lost with the second part on how to get the number of combinations that either start or end with an even number.

Comment: you mean repetition of digit is not allowed?

Comment: HINT for the 'start or end with even digit' part: figure out how many start and end with an odd digit, and subtract those from the total you found.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed a choice of $9$ numbers for each of the $5$ entries in the combination, the number of options is not $\frac{9!}{(9-5)!}$, as you suggest.

For example, if I was playing a game where I could choose any number between $1$ and $7$ three times over, the number of choices would be $7^3$.

In terms of working out the second part, perhaps you can think of it another way. If you know how many choices you'd normally have, but then I *restrict* you to having a great many fewer (in this case by insisting that your combination either starts or ends with an even number), you could perhaps try to work out how many choices you've lost.

As an example, if the restriction was that I had to pick $1$ as the first entry in my combination, I've lost $\frac{8}{9}$ of the options I originally had, yes?